# How to return bitset value in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

How do I return a bitset from a function in C++?

```
bitset<32>* check() {
  bitset<32> v8;
  for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    v8[i] = 1;
  }
  return v8;
}
```

I got this error:

```
[Error] cannot convert 'std::bitset<32u>' to std::bitset<32u>*' in return
```

Comment: Well, do you want to return a bitset or a pointer to a bitset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to return a value as a pointer, in this case you really should just return by value. Using a pointer is nonsense here.

```
bitset<32> check() {
  bitset<32> v8;
  for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    v8[i] = 1;
  }

  return v8;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a bitset from a function that is declared to return a pointer to a bitset.

You can return a bitset from a function that is declared to return a bitset:

```
bitset<32>  check()
//        ^ note the lack of * which would be syntax for a pointer declaration
```

Comment: @narecia it does. Perhaps you made a mistake.